# JavaScript Error (Uncaught TypeError: $.initNamespaceStorage is not a function)

Tags: magento2.2, javascript, jquery

We are running a Magento multi site and on ONE site only, I get this error
Uncaught TypeError: $.initNamespaceStorage is not a function

All sites use the same theme (just some differences between them..), any clues ?

### Thank you for helping me
Here is the script

```
        require.config({
            deps: [
                'jquery',
                'mage/translate',
                'jquery/jquery-storageapi'
            ],
            callback: function ($) {
                'use strict';

                var dependencies = [],
                    versionObj;

                $.initNamespaceStorage('mage-translation-storage');
                $.initNamespaceStorage('mage-translation-file-version');
                versionObj = $.localStorage.get('mage-translation-file-version');

                 if (versionObj.version !== '92817ddfc8670bafd7f41084a570359ae57c4623') {
                    dependencies.push(
                        'text!js-translation.json'
                    );

                }

                require.config({
                    deps: dependencies,
                    callback: function (string) {
                        if (typeof string === 'string') {
                            $.mage.translate.add(JSON.parse(string));
                            $.localStorage.set('mage-translation-storage', string);
                            $.localStorage.set(
                                'mage-translation-file-version',
                                {
                                    version: '92817ddfc8670bafd7f41084a570359ae57c4623'
                                }
                            );
                        } else {
                            $.mage.translate.add($.localStorage.get('mage-translation-storage'));
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please replace your $ with jQuery and also share some code related to that place.

Comment: Here is the error :
-----------------------------------------
(index):233 Uncaught TypeError: $.initNamespaceStorage is not a function
    at callback ((index):233)
    at Object.execCb (require.js:114)
    at Module.check (require.js:56)
    at Module.<anonymous> (require.js:73)
    at require.js:11
    at require.js:75
    at each (require.js:3)
    at Module.emit (require.js:75)
    at Module.check (require.js:61)
    at Module.<anonymous> (require.js:73)
-------------------------------------------

Comment: Have you check the jquery version? In my case there is a jquery clash loading in a module that creating this problem

Answer (score 1):

This is because jquery/jquery-storageapi might not have been loaded already. To fix the issue, vendor/dhl/module-ui/view/frontend/web/js/model/checkout/storage.js needs to require jquery/jquery-storageapi in its define like:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'jquery/jquery-storageapi'
], function ($, quote) {
```

Get Detailed Reference Here - https://github.com/netresearch/dhl-module-ui/issues/4

Thanks
Vibhore

Comment: Yes but Magento_Dhl module is not enabled...

Comment: If you can enable Dhl module then do that, otherwise what is your module name you can enable that.